# Align controls side by side in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a LinkButton. When clicked it opens an image as attached in Screenshot.

[image]

I want to view content and image side by side like i want push text content to left so that I can view both side by side.

```html
    <iframe allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen
        msallowfullscreen id="frameB" draggable="true" runat="server" scrolling="yes" style="width: 69%;
        max-width: 1500px; height: 495px;margin-top:-675px"></iframe>
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: https://imgur.com/NmKy0Wt . I Want like this

Comment: We can't answer this without a proper sample.

Comment: I have attached full code image since i dunno how to add code in comments sections. https://imgur.com/vRk7JUX